# Find all consecutive numbers in an int[]

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I want to find all the consecutive numbers  in a an ordered int[8] of casual numbers from 0 to 31. The consecutive numbers must be from minimum length of 3 and a max of 5 numbers.

In the example the last give me very real problem.

ex:

```
int[] = new int[] { 3,7,14,16,23, 28, 29 ,30 } // no  result (28,29 is length of 2 numbers)

int[] = new int[] { 4,5,6,7,18, 19, 20 ,21 }  // 4,5,6,7 (yes! length of 4!!)

int[] = new int[] { 2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9 } // two results : 2,3,4 and 5,6,7,8,9
```

I don't want *the solution* but just an example of how approach the question because I'm trying using generals and I'm really stuck!

Really thanks for help!

Christian

-this is the code from where I started (not soup from my kitchen)

```
public partial class Test2 : Form
{
    public Test2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Test2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          

         int[] numbers = new[] { 21, 4, 5, 22, 17, 6, 20, 23 };

      //  int[] numbers = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        foreach (Campo r in FindRanges(numbers, 3))
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(string.Join(", ", r.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
        }



    }


    struct Campo : IEnumerable<int>
    {
        readonly int _start;
        readonly int _count;

        public Campo(int start, int count)
        {
            _start = start;
            _count = count;
        }

        public int Start
        {
            get { return _start; }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return _count; }
        }

        public int End
        {
            get { return _start + _count - 1; }

        }

        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _count; ++i)
            {
                yield return _start + i;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {

            return this.GetEnumerator();

        }


        public static Campo operator +(Campo x, int y)
        {
            return new Campo(x.Start, x.Count + y);
        }

        public Campo removefirst()
        {
            return new Campo(this.Start + 3, this.Count);
        }

        public Campo removelast()
        {
            return new Campo(this.Start, this.Count - 1);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<Campo> FindRanges(IEnumerable<int> source, int minCount)
    {


        var ordered = source.OrderBy(x => x);

        Campo r = default(Campo);

        foreach (int value in ordered)
        {

            if (r.Count == 0)
            {
                r = new Campo(value, 1);
                continue;
            }


            if (r.Count == 5)
            {
                r = r.removefirst();

                continue;
            }

            if (value == r.End)
            {
               continue;
            }


            if ((value == 0 || value == 8 || value == 16 || value == 24) && (r.Count > minCount))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if ((value == 7 || value == 15 || value == 23 || value == 31) && (r.Count == 1))
            {
                continue;
            }

            else if (value == r.End + 1)
            {
               r += 1;
            }
            else
            {

                if (r.Count >= minCount)
                {
                    yield return r;
                }


                r = new Campo(value, 1);
            }
        }


        if (r.Count >= minCount)
        {
            yield return r;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Where's the code you used to solve this?

Comment: if (r.Count == 5) // better (r.count > 5)
            {
                r = r.removefirst();

                continue;
            }

Comment: Start with a sheet of paper, as Jon suggests. It is often easier to begin with a clean plate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sorry for the late update but time is very oppressor....

This my final solution with all necessary limits (for my needs) for serier.
Thank you all

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Sequences(IEnumerable<int> input, bool ascen = false, int min = 3)
    {
        int ord = ascen == false ? -1 : 1;

        input = ord == -1 ? input.OrderByDescending(x => x) : input.OrderBy(x => x);

        var seq = new List<List<int>>();
        foreach (var i in input)
        {
            var existing = seq.FirstOrDefault(lst => lst.Last() + ord == i);
            if ((existing == null) || (seq.Last().Count == 5) || i == 7 || i == 15 || i == 23)

                seq.Add(new List<int> { i });
            else
                existing.Add(i);
        }
        return min <= 1 ? seq : seq.Where(lst => lst.Count >= min);
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you take some examples and write them out on paper. Carefully work out what you're intuitively doing when you try to solve them by hand - and convert that into code.

You'll probably want to keep a count of how many values you've already found in the sequence, and what the previous value was...

Comment: Nice description of the "solution"... maybe it also helps Christian to know that each number in the sequence only needs to be looked at once; no backtracking or so is necessary.

Comment: At time of my answer I've done in the way you suggest and from your site I've learned many things on C#! Thanks a lot! Really!

Answer (score 1):

pseudo code:

1-sort the array in ascending order
2-

```
int count = 0
for i = 0 to array.length - 2
    if  {array[i + 1] - array[i] = 1 then
        count+=1
    else count=0}
    if { count >= 3 and count <= 5 then found}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it depends if your problem is always limited to that constraints, I mean int[8] array, 0-31, and 3-5, but if it isn't, I guess your problem couldn't be solved by a naive algorithm.

I mean, let's say we have this array:

```
int[] = new int[] { 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 };
```

and your subset constraint, i.e. *"consecutive numbers sets must be from minimum length of 3 and a max of 5 numbers"*.

A naive algorithm that starts from the first element to the last and fills the biggest possible consecutive subset, will yield these two subsets:

`[2,3,4,5,6] [7,8,9,10,11]`

In this solution 12 is in no partitions, but obviously there is another feasible solution (actually more than one) that includes all the numbers, that is for example:

`[2,3,4,5] [6,7,8,9] [10,11,12]`

Therefore, you can have several possibilities:

1. The 1st solution is OK, you don't need to cover as much as possible a found consecutive set
2. The 2nd solution is OK, you need to cover as much as possible a found consecutive set
3. The 2nd solution is OK, you need to cover as much as possible a found consecutive set, and possibly with the lowest possible number of subset

In the first case, you can do as other answerer pointed out (hey man, Jon Skeet answered to you ! :P).
Conversely, in the 2nd and 3rd case it's much more complicated because it's a [Knapsack type problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) i.e. an NP complete problem, (the 3rd case in particular sounds to me like [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)).

That's my two cents, obviously, I repeat, the problem doen't exist if you have always the same array size, range and subset constraints...

Comment: have always the same array size, range and subset constraints... and other limit: 0 (obviusly),8,16,24 can't ends the range and 7,15,23,31 can't start the range...

Comment: So you can even hardcode everything, actually you can have at most 28 set of 3 consecutive elements, 27 of 4 consecutive elements and 26 of 5 consecutive elements :-P (and this without including your last limits)

Comment: yes i know... but i'd like to generalize.... and I know is over my ability (@ the moment I hope ;-P  )

Comment: OK, well the first think to do is follow the advice of Jon Skeet. Then, practically speaking, I would avoid `yield` construct because it's not easy to understand for a beginner (sorry, if I'm supposing wrong) and I would also prefer to use `List<T>` or other built-in collection instead of building a new one (you can also use it internally in your `Campo` if you wish). Then, last but not least, `structs` are supposed to be for value types (to extremely simplify the problem, they're for very small objects, not for collections). Use class instead.

Comment: ok! I've to start over... tomorrow here it's late (italy)... i'll post my solution in some days . Thanks to all!!

Comment: Yes, it was late (I'm italian too). Infact I wrote "think" instead of "thing" :P

Answer (score 0):

1) Split given array in List of consecutive numbers (you said array is already order)

2) When adding to list if list already has 5 elements add to new list

3) Lists of Count > 2 are your results